# OpenVPN - SSH into OpenVPN client from OpenVPN server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openvpn

good day all

*note: I had a look at this [relevant link](https://serverfault.com/questions/714574/forward-ssh-to-openvpn-client-via-ufw) but it does not seem applicable since I am not forwarding my ssh, maybe between interfaces but that is already done*

I have a remote VPS Server, its purpose mainly as a easy access point for all my/colleagues devices, i.e. my home server, mobile, laptop,desktop,etc.

My openvpn server has `client-to-client` and `ccd` options configured working perfectly.

SSH'ing into another device by its given IP works perfectly, e.g.

```
../../.openvpn/ccd/

android-phone
    ifconfig-push 10.0.0.34 10.0.0.33

windows-laptop
    ifconfig-push 10.0.0.30 10.0.0.29
```

if both devices are connected, then in my android terminal,

```
ssh user@10.0.0.30
```

I can access my laptop perfectly, no issues, but whilst is my server terminal, server meaning OpenVPN server

```
ssh user@10.0.0.29
ssh user@10.0.0.30
ssh 10.0.0.29
ssh 10.0.0.30
```

all yield this error

```
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.29 port 22: Connection timed out
```

my iptables as follows

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data /* FTP-Data IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp /* FTP-Ctrl IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* SSH IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp /* SMTP IN (iface:ALL) */ state ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:whois /* Whois IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:domain /* DNS IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:http /* HTTP IN {NER}(iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:https /* HTTPS IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* HTTPS IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ntp /* NTP/OPENVPN IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9800 /* TRANSMISSION IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Ping Request/Reply IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Ping Request/Reply OUT (iface:ALL) */
```

and NAT table

```
iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere             to:{openvpn-server}
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/24          anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

and lastly, routing

```
netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.0.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 tun0
10.0.0.0        10.0.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG        0 0          0 tun0
default         *               0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 venet0
```

anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your openvpn server's ip is `10.0.0.2`, then run this:

`iptables -I POSTROUTING -t nat -d 10.0.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 10.0.0.2`

and try again.

I had the same issue before, and with this solution I fixed it.

Comment: could you possibly give a short explaination why/how this works, to my understanding the only plausable explanation for the connection failed is since the ssh is created on the venet0 interface, why do I need to "postroute" this to my server vpn ip and not straight to say the venet0?

Comment: You **must** post details of your OpenVPN server config in order to determine its IP.  Please add the server config file to your initial question.